# Rspec controller spec returning undefined method 'where'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Trying to build a controller spec using rspec on a rails controller I have named "API::ZipsController".

The controller accepts a parameter called "zip_code" and returns an active record model and 200 status.

However, when I run rspec the test fails with `NoMethodError:` `undefined method 'where' for Zip:Module`. I believe this is because 'where' is an instance method, not a class method so I will need to stub/mock it? Unfortunately I have not had any luck in resolving the problem as of yet.

zips_controller_spec.rb:

```
describe API::ZipsController do
require 'spec_helper'
it "returns 200 status with zones data" do
        get 'show', zip_code: "V9A1B2"
        response.should be_success
  end
end
```

api/zips_controller.rb - (working):

```
class API::ZipsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    zip = Zip.where(zip_code: params[:zip_code].upcase.slice(0..2))
    render json: zip, status: 200
  end
end
```

zip.rb (model):

```
class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
def as_json(options)
super(:only => [:zip_code])
end
end
```

Comment: aren't you missing a require in your spec?

Comment: @moeabdol yes, edited my code post above to include 'spec_helper'. It was in my code all along though.

Comment: Can you show Zip class?

Comment: actually where is a class method! Can you show Zip class?

Comment: @moeabdol added the zip class to the post above.. it's just used to super the as_json definition. I tried to use "find" instead of where but get the error 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Zip with 'id'={:zip_code=>"V9A"})' because it tries to find it by id, where I need to find by the zip_code column which 'where' seemed to work for

Comment: @ihaztehcodez see above comment

Comment: It's strange that you do not get the same error with `find`.  Does it work as expected if you prefix `Zip` with `::` like: `::Zip.where(...)`?

Comment: @ihaztehcodez actually I do get the same error with find `undefined method find`

Comment: @ihaztehcodez I was using postman and reading the rails error before, but for the rspec error the Find method error is the same as the where error

Comment: do you have this spec under spec/controllers? if you do remove it and place it under spec/apis and rename it to zip_api_spec.rb

Comment: And with the double colon prefix?  `::Zip.where(...)`?

Comment: @moeabdol I did have it in spec/controllers yes. I moved it to spec/apis but still have it as type: :controller. Should I remove that too?

Comment: @JonGirard yes! and make type: :api

Comment: @ihaztehcodez still fails with the double prefix. I'm searching my code to see if it is accidentally defined anywhere as a module

Comment: @moeabdol we may be getting somewhere, no longer getting the `where` error and now it gives error `undefined method 'get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::APIZipsController::GETApiZones:0x007fb59438b520>`

Comment: Here's a crazy idea... are you using the `rubyzip` gem in you Gemfile?  It defines a `Zip` module...

Comment: @JonGirard or you can try type: :request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Zip` module defined *somewhere* that is conflicting with your `Zip` model.  It could be somewhere in your code or something trickier like the use of the `rubyzip` gem.

You could namespace the model in another module as suggested in another answer or rename the model to something else like `Zipcode`.

Comment: HA! I don't believe it.. I DID have the rubyzip gem in my gemfile.lock.. must have been a dependency of something. I renamed my Zip model to Zipcode and everything seems to work. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
  require 'spec_helper'

  describe API::ZipsController, type: :controller do
    let(:zip_code) { "V9A1B2" }
    let(:params) { { zip_code: zip_code } }
    let(:zip) { double('zip') }

    before do
      allow(Api::Zip).to receive(:where).with(zip_code) { zip }
    end

    it "returns 200 status with zones data" do
      get 'show', params
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

#### Update

Try to put your `Zip` class under a module, say `Api` and put it under `app/models/api/zip.rb` file:

```
module Api
  class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
    def as_json(options)
      super(:only => [:zip_code])
    end
  end
end
```

And, then try the above code.

Comment: Not sure I would reach for a mock so quickly.  Given that the error is an undefined method for `Zip:Module`, I suspect OP has a `API::Zip` module defined somewhere and this would just make the test pass without fixing anything.

Comment: Lets wait for his response. Then, based on that, I can update my answer.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam thank you for your answer, unfortunatley this did not work. Still returns "undefined method 'where' for Zip:Module".

Comment: @ihaztehcodez I'm not sure what it means by "Zip:Module" because I'm only defining it in one file as API::ZipsController in the rails controller.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam Hmm, I now get the error `Failure/Error: allow(Zip).to receive(:where).with(zip_code) { zip }
       Zip does not implement: where`

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam I tried switching 'where' for 'find' in my zips_controller and get the same `undefined method 'find' for Zip:Module` error too

Comment: `Zip` is a class, why is it saying as module? Do you have any `Zip` module defined anywhere in your code?

Comment: @JonGirard can you please try my updated answer again?

Comment: Thank you for your help @KMRakibulIslam

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to see that your problem is fixed.